# How do I mass update an Eloquent model without a where condition?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update all rows in a table with a new value for an Eloquent model. Laravel's documentation gives the following example for mass updates with Eloquent:

```
App\Flight::where('active', 1)
          ->where('destination', 'San Diego')
          ->update(['delayed' => 1]);
```

But I don't need the where condition. Ideally, I'd be able to run something like this:

```
App\Flight::update(['delayed' => 1]);
```

which omits the `where` clause. But this gives the error:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically on line 1
```

**How can I mass update all the rows in my table using Eloquent?** I want to avoid using the `DB::table('flights')->update(...)` style if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using by running

```
App\Flight::query()->update(['delayed' => 1]);
```

The `query()` method creates a new query builder instance, but without any initial clauses (like `where` conditions). Additional operations like `update()` can be chained after it.

Comment: Why not use `::all()`?

Comment: `::all()` actually retrieves the instances from the database.